# Cannot access DataGridView columns after setting Datasource

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a strange problem. I am binding a `datatable` to `DataGridView` by setting `.DataSource` property and after that I cannot access DataGridView columns.

```
Dim dtPML As New DataTable

dtPML.Columns.Add("ID_IN_DATASOURCE", Type.GetType("System.String"))
dtPML.Columns.Add("SELECTED", Type.GetType("System.Boolean"))
dtPML.Columns.Add("DESCRIPTION", Type.GetType("System.String"))

grdHorizonPMLRadit.DataSource = dtPML

'next line fails with NullReferenceException
grdHorizonPMLRadit.Columns("ID_IN_DATASOURCE").Visible = False
```

When checking `grdHorizonPMLRadit.Columns.Count` it shows zero columns, although `CType(grdHorizonPMLRadit.DataSource, DataTable).Columns.Count` returns 3.

Why hasn't `DataGridView` generated columns from `Datatable`?

`.AutoGenerateColumns` property is set to true. Is it being done in another thread or only when grid is drawn? If I just set Datasource and don't touch .Columns collection until form has been fully loaded then columns are accessible.

Strange thing is, I have done this before and it worked all right. I have recently switched to Visual Studio 2013, is there some kind of changes in `Datagridview` data handling?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the behavior you noted is *normal*. Although you set the `DataSource` property, the `DatagridView` won't create columns until the grid is displayed.

Try to move this line of code in [DataGridView.DataBindingComplete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.databindingcomplete.aspx) event to be sure the columns are created:

```
grdHorizonPMLRadit.Columns("ID_IN_DATASOURCE").Visible = False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very old, so I'd like to give a generalized answer.

TD;DL: **Your DataGridView has to be inside a Form**. It has nothing to do with being displayed.

Example code:

```
Dim dataGrid = New DataGridView()

' This is needed to make the DataTable apply to DataGridView
Dim form = New System.Windows.Forms.Form()       
form.Controls.Add(dataGrid)

dataGrid.DataSource = createDataTable()

' dataGrid.Columns.Count() > 0
```

Comment: *Displayed* is probably not the good word, but the event I mention exists for a good reason. I was able to make it work in rare cases moving the code in Form Load event (and already seen that as an answer here), but there is no garantee it will work. Again, the event I mention exists for a good reason.